# Can't find Pip executable on Mac OS X

Tags: pip

I've read the Pip related responses and still have this question.  I'm trying to install pip on Mac OS X 10.6.8. In brief, I run `sudo python get-pip.py` and get an error that the pip `Requirement is already up to date.`

But I don't see a 'pip' executable file in the expected directory and can't run pip. Should there be a file called pip in the target pip folder?

More detail:

I'm following directions at: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

1) Used `ez_install` to install setuptools

2) bashed:

> curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py $ 
>   sudo python get-pip.py
>   Response is
>   Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
>   ... I can see a lot of files in this directory

3) I then try to use pip:

> /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip install virtualenv
>   Get back > pip: is a directory

4) I try

> / Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip/pip install virtualenv
>   -bash: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip/pip: No such file or directory

I look in the above path and can see the  pip folder, with numerous files including `__main__` and `__init__` but no file named pip. Should there be one? if so, how might I clear out the old install and reinstall?

Thanks for any advice!
SL

Comment: Have you tried using pip without a leading directory?  Just ``pip install x``?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I successfully installed `pip` from the Github repositories on Max OS X 10.9:

Get `pip` repository:

> $ git clone https://github.com/pypa/pip

Perform setup:

> $ cd pip
>   $ sudo python setup.py install

That's it. A test run should give something like:

> $ pip -V
>   pip 1.6.dev1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.6.dev1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

And my `PATH` environment variable is set to:

> $ echo $PATH
>   /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile